# How to populate id and it's value in XSL attribute as <ParentElement id="abc:efg:id:hij:12345.111111.0">

Tags: select, xslt, nodes

How to populate id and it's value in XSL attribute? 
In the process of converting source xml to target xml. Need to have XSL file. Can anyone help me on this XSLT transformation?

```
<xsl:template match="ParentElement/Number">
    <xsl:element name="ParentElement">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,15)"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

I have tried the above code snippet.
Actual Output: 12345.111111.0

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the XML that this template matches on input as well as the desired output XML that it should produce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing your XML but perhaps you want something like:

```
<xsl:template match="ParentElement/Number">
    <ParentElement id="abc:efg:id:hij:{substring(.,1,15)}"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ParentElement>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I have one more question, since I am new to XSLT converison. How to populate the tag in below format?
<newElement>
 <id>abc:def:ij:klmn:0111901.0</id>
</newElement>

Comment: It doesn't work well in StackOverflow when you ask supplementary questions in comments on an answer. The right approach is to ask a new question, with all the information that's needed to provide an answer. The way you "populate a tag" (correct terminology: create child nodes for an element) depends on where the data is going to come from.

Answer (score 0):

just use:

```
  <xsl:template match="ParentElement/Number">
    <xsl:element name="ParentElement">
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,15)"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```